# Why has my reputation gone from 21 to 1?

Tags: discussion, reputation

It was in the 20's about a year ago. (Most of those points were from an answer I posted in stack exchange's Math group.) Now it's 1. The only thing I can think of is getting "This question already has an answer here:" once or twice. Is there a history of my rep changes/votes, etc?

Answer (score 6):

> It was in the 20's about a year ago.

You only appear to have been a member of this site (Pro Webmasters) for "3 months" [according to your Webmasters profile](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/77870/jack-ritter?tab=profile), and all your (Webmasters) rep seems to have been gained from a single question asked just a few days ago.

> (Most of those points were from an answer I posted in stack exchange's Math group.)

Note that the different Stack Exchange sites (Webmasters, Mathematics, etc.) all have separate rep scores.

However, you "only" appear to have been a member of the Mathematics stack site for 7 months, [according to your Mathematics profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/406418/jack-ritter?tab=profile) (during which time there doesn't appear to have been any activity at all?). If questions were closed then it's possible that they have since been deleted, so you may have lost rep that way? (Although "duplicates" aren't usually deleted in my experience, but maybe this depends on the site?)

You do, however, have a [rep of 51 on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5927755/jack-ritter?tab=profile) and on SO you have indeed been a member for over a year - maybe it was this site you are remembering?!

> Is there a history of my rep changes/votes, etc?

Within your profile page on the respective site you can see your reputation changes over time since you joined. Profile > Activity > Reputation. For example, on the Webmasters main site: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/77870/jack-ritter?tab=reputation&sort=time

Comment: Now I get it. I just saw in my profile that I belong to 5 different communities. I was confused because they're all stack something. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, these sites are all part of the Stack Exchange "Network" of sites. They are separate sites, but intrinsically linked behind the scenes. Questions can be migrated from one site to another if deemed off-topic on one and on-topic on another (some sites do overlap a bit). There are [currently 169 sites in the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), which is growing. You can propose a new site in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) and once you gain sufficient interest, followers, sample questions, etc a new site can be created...

Comment: (I hope this is commenting on my own post): How did u get a rep of 25 THOUSAND points??

Comment: Blood, sweat and pure dedication, no seriously... just gradually over 7 years and 800+ answers. Some popular questions go "viral" and get many upvotes, some questions get "bounties" applied. StackOverflow has 500+ users that have over 100 THOUSAND points!